# What is a call back method in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What the heck is a call back method in rails? I see this term being used everywhere while I learn about controllers and models. Can someone provide examples please?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html

Comment: I find Rails Guides explains things very well. Please check out [the chapter about callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#callbacks-overview).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ref [`ActiveRecord::Callbacks`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html#M001375) for the Callbacks w.r.to Activerecord

```
Callbacks are hooks into the lifecycle of an Active Record object that allow you 
to trigger logic before or after an alteration of the object state. This can be 
used to make sure that associated and dependent objects are deleted when destroy 
is called (by overwriting before_destroy) or to massage attributes before they‘re
validated (by overwriting before_validation). As an example of the callbacks
initiated, consider the Base#save call for a new record
```

Take an example you have a `Subscription` model and you have a column `signed_up_on` which will contains the date at which subscription is created. For this `w/o Callbacks` you can do something like following in your `controller`.

```
@subscription.save
@subscription.update_attribute('signed_up_on', Date.today)
```

Which will perfectly fine but if suppose you have 3-4 methods in your application where subscription is get create. So to achieve it you have repeat the code in all the places which is redundant.

To avoid this you can use `Callbacks` and `before_create` Callback here. So whenever your object of subscription is get create it will  assign today's date to `signed_up_on`

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_create :record_signup

    private
      def record_signup
        self.signed_up_on = Date.today
      end
end
```

Following is the list of all the Callbacks

```
after_create
after_destroy
after_save
after_update
after_validation
after_validation_on_create
after_validation_on_update
before_create
before_destroy
before_save
before_update
before_validation
before_validation_on_create
before_validation_on_update
```